# Order of Differential Equation containing integration term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the order and degree of the following equation?
$$\Big(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\Big)^3  +  \frac{dy}{dx}  =   \int y dx.$$

Comment: What are your thoughts about that?

Comment: A good first step would be to write down the definitions of "order" and "degree".  You should consider including those definitions in your question.

Comment: Definition is what I am looking for. This question was asked in our state level examination and the government's exam conducting board has said that the answer is order=2 and degree=3. So to challenge this answer I need to submit proof of legitimacy of the answer as a legal procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends. When you have an integration term, it's not longer an ODE, thus it doesn't have the same classification.

If you want to turn it into an ODE, you'd have to differentiate, thus rasing the order to $3$:

$$3 (y'')^2 y'''+y''=y$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=\int y\,dx$. Then the ODE form of your mixed integral-differential equation is
$$
(u''')^3+u''=u
$$
which has order $3$ and is polynomial with degree $3$.

Note that in the given form this is not an ODE and thus it makes no sense to speak of a degree.